# Is there a real power series with radius of convergence 1 that converges at 1 but not at -1?

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

I can find a power series that has radius of convergence 1 but since any series that converges absolutely converges, I cannot find any that converges at 1 but diverges at -1... Can you help me? Thank you!

Comment: $\sum (-1)^n {1\over n}x^n$.

Comment: Beware that a series that has radius of convergence $R$, is absolutely convergent for $|z| < R$. The behavior at the boundary is a difficult question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The power series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n {x^n\over n}$ has radius of convergence $r=1$, converges for $x=1$, but diverges for $x=-1$ (this gives the Harmonic series).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is of great help!

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun, if you want a series which converges everywhere on the unit circle except for a single point $e^{i\theta}$, you might look at the series

$$f(z) = z + \frac12 z^2 + \frac13 z^3 + \dots$$

which converges everywhere on the unit circle, except for the point $z=1$, and then consider

$$g(z) = f(e^{-i\theta}z)$$

This provides a solution for your particular question by taking $\theta = \pi$.

Comment: Thank you for this, I like it!